# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 in Asus ROG 552VW

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am new to Ubuntu. Never used it before. I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside my Windows 10.

Heres what I did :

1. Downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 from official website
2. Made a bootable USB drive
3. While in the setup, no matter what I click "Install Ubuntu"/"Try Ubuntu without installing", it goes to the next loading screen and freezes. The installation completely becomes frozen.

I have seen many tutorials on Youtube on installing Ubuntu and I can't find what I am doing wrong.

My specs:
Asus ROG 552VW running on Legacy mode

I have Windows 10 installed in legacy mode. I managed to install Ubuntu after setting nouvaeu.modeset=0 , now the problem is my graphics are lagging.
After installing Nvidia drivers I'm stuck at the login loop :(

Comment: did you try changing you usb drive? i.e Creating a new bootable usb drive?

Comment: nope, but tried creating new bootable using different software

Comment: If you're doing it in Ubuntu or derivatives I recommend MKUSB; in Windows use Rufus. Also your notebook requires additional steps due to the Nvidia graphics (`nomodeset`) and, unless you're dual booting with another OS previously installed in Legacy, there no point in doing so for Ubuntu. Whenever doable always use UEFI. Please edit your question and add the information regarding whether you intend to have a dual boot or not, what's the other OS already installed if applicable and how that OS has been installed, so I can answer with specific instructions.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have updated the question.